# What is the best way to create paginated Subscription for Collection with Categories

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor, I was trying to use categories my posts

and using paginated-subscription package I am able to load 10 posts at a time and use load more button at the bottom to fetch next 10 posts,

but when I display posts in different categories I can't display 10 posts in each categories as the Server publishes only 10 posts at a time,

I couldn't figure out how to publish for all categories 10 posts in each. How shall I publish the posts in such a way that i get 10 posts in each category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out the [`paginated-subscription`s' source code](https://github.com/percolatestudio/paginated-subscription/blob/master/paginated_subscription.js). And found out that you can pass arguments to the publication. So you can do something like this for you publication:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(category, limit) {
  var query = {}
  if(category) query.category = category
  return Posts.find(query, {limit: limit})
});
```

The last argument to the publication has to be the limit (["*which expects as a final argument the current number of documents to display*"](https://github.com/percolatestudio/paginated-subscription#usage)). In your call to `Meteor.subscribeWithPagination` you can now do this:

```
Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('posts', 'someCategory', 10)
```